# Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?

Tags: поддержка, faq

На сайте, над которым я работаю, возникла проблема с CSS, HTML или JavaScript.

Я бы хотел кратко описать проблему и дать ссылку на мой (внешний) сайт. Могу ли я поступить таким образом, вместо того чтобы выкладывать на Stack Overflow фрагмент кода? Ведь проблему гораздо легче обнаружить на рабочем сайте.

Если нет, то почему?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации: «[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/564240)»</sub>

Comment: Для комментариев: `[Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263)`

Answer (score 31):

## Нет.

---

Основная миссия сайта Stack Overflow – составление базы знаний состоящей из проблем (вопросов) и их решений (ответов) полезной людям в ситуациях, выходящих *за рамки* изначальной поставленного вопроса. Вопрос, состоящий исключительно из гиперссылки, не позволяет достичь этой цели по двум причинам:

1. **Такой вопрос всегда будет *слишком узким/частным*:** проблема будет существовать только на одной странице в данный конкретный момент времени. Вряд ли кто-либо напишет код, полностью совпадающий с вашим (даже если столкнется с точно такой же проблемой), а как только решение найдено и ошибка устранена, ссылка становится неактуальной (воспроизвести проблему уже не получится).
2. **Без кода, с помощью которого можно продемонстрировать проблему, этот вопрос даже нельзя назвать вопросом:** предположим, вы получили *прекрасный* ответ. Как его найдет другой человек с такой же проблемой? Это произойдет только если вы хорошо поняли суть проблемы и подробно ее описали в теле самого вопроса, иначе ваш вопрос будет содержать только общее описание (и никакого кода). Сколько вопросов с одним и тем же необходимо посмотреть, пока я не найду то, что наиболее соответствует моей проблеме?

Такой вопрос, скорее всего, будет закрыт как вопрос не по теме: *«Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)».*

### Что нужно сделать вместо этого?

Отредактируйте вопрос. Сузьте проблему до такой степени, чтобы вы могли описать ее с помощью полезного допускающего возможность поиска заголовка и *небольшого* фрагмента кода. Не нужно расписывать вопрос на всю страницу – постарайтесь представить, в чем конкретно может заключаться проблема и где тот фрагмент кода, который позволяет ее воспроизвести. Не знаете, как это сделать? Спросите!

Затем *вставьте код*, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы в вопрос – возможно, в виде примера кода, используя [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). Поскольку для некоторых они более привычны, дополнительно используйте [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) и/или [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Да, это сторонние сервисы, и они могут быть временно недоступны, поэтому **убедитесь в том, что ваш вопрос поймут и *без* посещения этих сайтов**.

### Советы по отладке

Перед отладкой CSS или JavaScript убедитесь в **верности** исходного HTML–кода. ["Ломаный" HTML](http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/185qvo/this_page_has_many_unclosed_h3_tags_which_leads/) – одна из самых частых причин возникновения ошибок, при этом различные обозреватели по-разному реагируют на неверный HTML. Проверка HTML–кода может выявить серьезные ошибки – например, отсутствие закрывающих тегов, дублирующиеся id-атрибуты. Хотя для корректного отображения страницы критичны и не все ошибки, перед отладкой вам все равно нужно максимально от них избавиться.

#### Средства валидации

- [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)
- [Validator.nu (X)HTML5 Validator](http://html5.validator.nu/)
- Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586207/validate-html-on-local-machine

#### Средства отладки

- [Инструменты разработчика](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools),  входящие в  Firefox
- [Средства разработчика](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), входящие в Google Chromium

Руководство по использованию этих средств: [JavaScript debugging for beginners](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

### См. также

- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code