# Вопрос для начинающих содержит возможно вредоносную ссылку. Следует ли править, если не уверен?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, спам

Наткнулся на общий вопрос, который может возникнуть у людей, несвязанных с разработкой. Вопрос содержит ссылку, некритичную для содержания вопроса. При этом ссылка ведёт на проект, из области, которая у меня ассоциируется с пирамидами Мавроди и гербалайфом (в этом вредоносность).

Я слабо знаком с тематикой (cryptocurrency) и не уверен, что мошеннический проект.

Можно другую более нейтральную ссылку подставить (в вопросы и ответы), но в силу подразумеваемого низкого технического уровня автора (и возможных читателей) этого вопроса, это может затруднить адаптацию решения автором.

В случае (заметных) сомнений, чьи интересы преобладают автора вопроса (оставить ссылку) или будущих читателей (заменить)?

Comment: Почему ссылку на сомнительное сообщение не добавили? Имхо, было бы понятнее о чем речь.

Comment: Конкретный пример отвлечёт от общего вопроса (последний параграф выше).

Answer (score 6):

Уверен, что такие вопрос и пример более понятны для читателей:

> Как получить словарь `{ parameter1: foo, parameter2: bar}` из адреса:

```
https://domain.tld/path?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar
```

Чем такие:

> Как получить словарь ... из адреса:
>
> http://someshittywebsitethatlookslikeurlshortener.casino/then/goes/long/path/unrelated/to/the/topic?suddenly=%47%34%%57%24%79%45%33%79%20%46%42

Цель сайта - собирать общие, универсальные, работающие для всех и понятно оформленные решения. А для адресной и персональной помощи есть другие сервисы. (Кстати, поэтому я обычно ставлю минусы вопросам и ответам про регулярки "для данного конкретного случая".)
Поэтому считаю, что нужно редактировать:

- Сразу: все подозрительные или нечитаемые ссылки.
- После того, как ответ получен, вообще все ссылки.

Answer (score 6):

**Заменить**, но не потому что она вредоносная, а потому что она попросту не нужна и не относится к тематике сайта, а значит в вопросе может встретиться лишь в качестве **примера**.

- Если интерес представляет сама ссылка (её URL или разметка), то для таких случаев, согласно [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-3), на уровне IANA (координаторов всея интернета) **зарезервированы несколько доменов-заглушек**: `example.com`, `example.org`, `example.net`. В большинстве случаев для "обезвреживания" достаточно будет заменить домен, и суть вопроса не пострадает.
- Если по ссылке находится материал, раскрывающий проблему (т. е. ссылка — неотъемлемая часть вопроса), то из этого материала необходимо выделить MCVE и разместить прямо в вопросе. А ссылку убрать. См. ["Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/181100)

  - Если без ТСа это сделать не представляется возможным, а сайт вызывает подозрения (можно попробовать подкрепить их отчётом с [Web of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/)), то ссылку тем не менее лучше заменить, а вопрос закрыть, попросив у ТСа MCVE. Закрытость вопроса не помешает разбирающимся прохожим при желании добавить MCVE.

Answer (score 4):

Когда нет уверенности, лучше, конечно, пропустить. Именно такая кнопка используется в очередях проверки на похожие ситуации. Здесь же вижу как минимум три возможных решения:

1. спросить в комментариях у автора о причинах использования именно этой ссылки, а не другой, более нейтральной.
2. обратиться за консультацией в чат/на Мету с указанием **конкретного** проблемного сообщения для коллегиального разбора ситуации.
3. поставить тревогу на сообщении, пусть <s>Чапай</s> модератор думает.

Comment: Не могли бы вы более развёрнуто о *"лучше, конечно, пропустить"*.  Я бы, к примеру, после того как автор принял ответ, поменял бы все ссылки на более нейтральные при наличии малейших сомнений в добротности ссылки. Так как автор уже нашёл решение, а будущим читателям всё равно, а StackOverflow сайт  рассчитан именно последнюю категорию обслуживать. Вопрос из категории "не упустил ли я что-то очевидное".

Comment: @jfs я не знаю как подробнее описать ситуацию "не уверен - не обгоняй". Точнее не вижу смысла в каком-то дальнейшем уточнении, т.к. это будет просто литьё воды. Если есть сомнения - предлагаю действовать как описано, если сомнений нет - то и вопрос бы, наверное, не возник. Не так ли?

Comment: я вижу *ноль* доводов в ответе в пользу того чтобы ссылку оставить. Явно укажите возможный вред по вашему мнению от изменения ссылки на нейтральную и как он сооизмеряется по вашему с риском что Stack Overflow  ссылка на возможно мошеннический сайт будет оставлена. Вы по сути рекомендуете в русскую рулетку играть, мол если не уверен на 100% что убьёт, то можно и на курок нажимать.

Comment: @jfs либо Вы потеряли "не" в своей аналогии с русской рулеткой, либо у нас недопонимание. Возможно, всё это из-за Вашего нежелания привести **конкретный** пример. А моё предложение в том, чтобы максимально прояснить причину использования именно той ссылки, которая была использована прежде чем что-то предпринимать с заменой. Поэтому у меня в ответе нет как доводов за, так и против. Нельзя выбрать что-то одно, когда вообще непонятно о чём речь.

Comment: Ещё раз: сьёмка, сцена дуэли. Есть сомнение, что пистолеты безопасны (к примеру, есть маленькая вероятность, что пистолет боевыми заряжен). Вопрос: поменяете ли вы пистолеты, зная что замена денег стоит? Или по принципу *"лучше, конечно, пропустить"*, *"не уверен - не обгоняй"* пусть актёры какими есть пистолетами пользуются (мы же не уверены что пистолеты опасны).

Comment: @jfs Вы видимо хотите, чтобы я дал ответ, который Вы заранее уже решили услышать. В таких случаях имеет смысл писать одновременно и вопрос, и ответ.

Comment: неверно. Как раз я хочу услышать мнения, отличающиеся от моего. Для этого я вопрос на Мете и задал. Если я ещё попросил в комментарии *обосновать* это мнение, то разве это слишком непомерная просьба (к примеру, явно упомянуть плюсы/минусы как вы их видите)