# Могу ли я оставить ссылку на github?

Tags: обсуждение

Могу ли я оставить ссылку на github, если кусок кода достаточно большой (многа букав)?

Можно ли, если я не могу найти ошибку, выложить код на [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) или оставить там ссылку на github?

Comment: какова цель? чтобы кто-то нашел ошибку в достаточно большом куске кода?

Comment: Да, чтобы найти ошибку

Comment: тогда ссылка вряд ли поможет. прежде всего нужно минимализировать код, как минимум определить место где происходит ошибка, а когда место определено, в нем обычно не очень много текста. в этом случае можно добавить дополнительно ссылку га вес код. Но просто ссылка на код скорее всего никого не привлечет

Comment: Скажем так, в 1ой программе я  вывожу статический массив данных на экран - работает корректно. Когда-же во 2ой программе я делаю массив динамическим и вывожу на экран посредством 1ой программы  - получаю неверный результат. Вторая программа включает в себя первую и надо найти в ней ошибку. Выкладывать программу целиком?

Comment: @GeoFructus стоит минимизировать пример - выбросить из обоих программ то, что не обязательно для воспроизведения ошибки. Просто сделайте копию проекта, и удалите из него весь код, кроме работы с проблемным массивами. И то, что получится в результате, выкладывайте.

Comment: Даже если предположить, что можешь, вряд ли кто-то станет выкачивать гитхаб-репозиторий, разбираться, что там происходит, запускать и дебажить. Но вообще, проблемный код должен быть в самом вопросе, хотя дополнительная ссылка на полную версию кода допускается. Тьфу.. Надо было ответ писать.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy почему только связанный, а не дубликат?

Comment: Для информации, сайт CodeReview - не для поиска ошибок в коде, а для вопросов по улучшению уже работающего кода

Comment: @alexolut, ну сайт обычно чинят или он просто меняется, т. е. гитхаб - более долговременное хранение и, соответственно, воспроизводимость. Так что по-моему, не дубликат.

Comment: @Qwertiy репозиторий тоже эволюционирует, можно дать, конечно, ссылку на коммит. Но суть не в этом. Суть в самодостаточности сообщения на SO. И здесь разницы нет, гитхаб это или чей-то хоумпейдж. Пока у SO нет договорённости со сторонним ресурсом наподобие imgur, это всё не позволяет считать сообщение самодостаточным. Так можно было бы и ссылки на гуглдрайв приводить, там тоже долго храниться может.

Comment: @alexolut, у меня в некоторых вопросах есть ссылки на облако.

Answer (score 7):

Даже если предположить, что можешь, вряд ли кто-то станет выкачивать гитхаб-репозиторий, разбираться, что там происходит, запускать и дебажить.

Проблемный код должен быть в самом вопросе, хотя окружающий его код может быть описан текстом. В таком случае можно разместить дополнительную ссылку на гитхаб, пастбин или другой ресурс, где будет находиться полная версия кода, которую можно будет запустить.

Стоит постараться по максимуму сократить кол, чтобы получился [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и уже его помещать в вопрос.